# Command 'bison name.y' doesn't work but not give out any error. system path correctly set up

Tags: powershell, bison

I'm trying to run the command `bison file_name.y` from PowerShell, but it does not work. the command seems to be executed by the shell in fact the shell returns to ask for input but does not produce any output. I also tried the command `bison file_name.y -d` but I got the same result. I have checked the system variables and are correctly set. In fact, `flex` works correctly, for which I followed the same procedure.

Comment: Barring errors, bison should not produce any output to the screen (nor should flex for that matter). Did `file_name.tab.c` get generated correctly?

Comment: this is the problem. file_name.tab.c does not appear. but no one error is detected

Comment: Maybe you need the call operator (&) like: `& bison file_name.y`

Comment: nothing has changed. it seems that the shell does not perform any operation when I write commands 'bison ...'